# Remove need for second T-SQL query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am loading some data into a repeater which is coming from two tables. The query against the second table is only selecting the MAX record though, and because of this complexity, I'm having to create a child repeater to then go off and find the Max record to display.

Table A: Activity List

```
ID  |  Activity
----+-----------------------
1   |  Change Oil Filter
2   |  Change brake fluid
3   |  Change brake rotors
```

Table B: Mechanics Log

```
ID | ActivityID  | Date        | Mechanic | Comment
---+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------
1  | 1           | 2019-27-06  | John     | Changed the oil filter
2  | 1           | 2019-26-06  | Sally    | No oil filters in stock.
3  | 2           | 2019-20-06  | Sally    | Brake fluid flushed.
```

As stated above, I can produce the following table using two repeaters (one inside the other) and it looks like this.

```
ActivityID   | Date        | Mechanic | Comment
-------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------
1            | 2019-27-06  | John     | Changed the oil filter
2            | 2019-20-06  | Sally    | Brake fluid flushed.    
3            |             |          |
```

My question is: How can I produce the same table but using only one repeater and 1 T-SQL query? Is it possible? The reason being is that this is a very simple list (shortened for this demonstration) of the full list I have to enable for my mechanics work log, and when i start going to 100+ activities that can be done on a vehicle, the page loads quite slow; assuming because it has to fire off the 2nd repeater + code for each record it has bound.

I also apologize I do not yet have a 'starting point' for you to work with, as nothing I have created has come even close to producing the result in one query. I am having trouble working out how I combine the first part of the query with the `MAX(Date)` of the 2nd table. Hoping for some assistance from the community to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below query to get the desired result -

**Sample Data**

```
Declare @ActivityList Table
(ID int, Activity varchar(100))

Insert into @ActivityList
values
(1   ,  'Change Oil Filter'    ),
(2   ,  'Change brake fluid'     ),
(3   ,  'Change brake rotors'    )


Declare @MechanicsLog Table
(ID int, ActivityID int, [Date] Date, Mechanic varchar(20), Comment varchar(50))

Insert into @MechanicsLog
values
(1  , 1     ,      '2019-06-27'  , 'John'     , 'Changed the oil filter'   ),
(2  , 1     ,      '2019-06-26'  , 'Sally'    , 'No oil filters in stock.' ),
(3  , 2     ,      '2019-06-20'  , 'Sally'    , 'Brake fluid flushed.'     )
```

**Query**

```
;With cte as
(select ActivityID, Max([Date]) [date] from  @MechanicsLog ml
Group By ActivityID
)
Select al.ID, al.Activity, cte.[Date], Mechanic, Comment 
from cte inner join @MechanicsLog ml 
on cte.ActivityID = ml.ActivityID and cte.[date] = ml.[Date]
right join  @ActivityList al on al.ID = ml.ActivityID
order by ID
```

Comment: I just ran this and it doesn't give me the desired output, as the Activity with no Log data against it does not show up in the results.

Comment: Ok, Try now, I have updated the query. Used right join so that it will give all activities records even it does not have any log data. Please check and Let me know.

Comment: Bravo! Fabulous Mukesh. Works great and MUCH faster than my original implementation. The page loads very fast like this.

Comment: Gr8, Happy to known that its help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you add use the ROW_NUMBER function to add a sequence to each activity ID, you can then filter that to only get the most recent for each activity ID.

```
select ActivityID, Date, Mechanic, Comment 
from 
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ActivityID order by Date desc) RowNumber
from MechanicsLog
) q1 
where RowNumber = 1
```

This gives you the "MAX" record for each ActivityID but with the rest of the record, so you can join to the Activity List table if you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
    act.ActivityID, Max(log.[Date]) as [Date]
from 
    ActivityList act 
inner join 
    MachineLog log on log.ActivityID = act.ActivityID
Group by 
    act.ActivityID
```

Comment: Grouping by ActivityID will guarantee 1 row per ActivityID - using distinct adds nothing useful.

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it solves the problem.